# Milnor's definition of smooth functions on manifolds as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

In Milnor's Topology from a differentiable viewpoint on page 1, functions on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^l$ are defined to be smooth if their partial derivatives exist and are continuous. Then he defines smooth manifolds as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$ (which I understand is equivalent to the abstract definition of manifolds due to Whitney's theorem).

My question is that while defining functions on a smooth manifold $M$, is it correct to say that the euclidean space $M$ is embedded in is assumed to have the standard smooth structure?

If so, what happens when that is not the case? For example consider the manifold $$M \subset \mathbb{R}, M = (-1,1)$$ with an atlas containing the single chart $$\phi : x \mapsto x^{1/9}$$
and define $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x^{1/3}$

Now $f$ is smooth because $f \circ \phi^{-1} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth.

The problem arises when on page 6, derivative of a smooth function on manifolds is defined to be $$df_x(h) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (f(x + th) - f(x))/t$$ the limit of which in our case doesn't exist at $x = 0$.

To be precise the actual derivative is the derivative of an extention of $f$ on open subsets of $M$ but in this case the two are the same.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^k$ are usually taken with the standard smooth structure given by the chart $(\mathbb{R}^k,Id)$. The smooth structure is important in determining if a function is smooth or not, because in some cases even if the set (for example $\mathbb{R}^k$) is the same, the smooth structure may not be equivalent (diffeomorphic). When they are not equivalent you can have cases where you get smoothness in one structure and not in the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $\mathbb{R}^k$ is always considered to have the standard smooth structure in this context.  If you have a manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^k$ with respect to some nonstandard smooth structure, then it is just not a manifold in Milnor's sense and his definitions do not apply.  You would instead need to use the general theory of abstract manifolds.